# Making an advent calendar on Python

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

I'm trying to create a python script that prints a different statement on every day of December leading up to Christmas.

Below is what I've tried so far as a test but it doesn't work :/

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

nov_27 = 2022-11-27
nov_28 = 2022-11-28

if today == nov_27:
    print("words")
elif today == nov_28:
    print("no words")
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

```
nov_27 = 2022-11-27
print(nov_27)
```

gives output

```
1984
```

as `2022-11-27` is treated as arithmetic by `python`, use `datetime.date` to create date object instance which you can compare with today e.g.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
nov_27 = date(2022,11,27)
nov_28 = date(2022,11,28)
if today == nov_27:
    print("today is nov_27")
if today == nov_28:
    print("today is nov_28")
```

gives (at 2022-11-27) output

```
today is nov_27
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

##### Code:

```py
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

nov_27 = date(2022, 11, 27)
nov_28 = date(2022, 11, 28)

if today == nov_27:
    print("words")
elif today == nov_28:
    print("no words")
```

##### Output:

```
words
```